# Problems using Aes to encrypt and decrypt strings in a Xamarin .NetStandard portable library

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, cryptography, .net-standard

I am working on a mobile Xamarin app that needs to encrypt and decrypt a string using Aes. The library I am working in is a .Net Standard 1.3 portable library using System.Security.Cryptography for the encryption classes.

I am having issues encrypting, and then decrypting the string. I have used references from [This article about encryption in portable libraries](https://xamarinhelp.com/cryptography-in-xamarin-forms/#comment-753) and also [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged(v=vs.110).aspx).

There have been many issues. First, when testing in visual studio I get a runtime exception:

> Result Message:    System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I tried editing packages.json to include this reference but nothing worked. I am still fairly new at software design so if anyone knows the solution to that it would be helpful, but that is not my real problem as I can still run tests in an android test runner. Not an efficient method of debugging.

Using the above references I created a class that SHOULD encrypt and decrypt a string. Encryption seems to work (on the android emulator), however I get one of two exceptions when decrypting, I cannot tell which one is actually preventing me.

> System.ArgumentException : Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from the index to the end of the source collection.

The other error I cannot replicate at the time of writing this question, but it is an error related to pkcs7 padding being too short;

The tests that I am running are:

```
[TestFixture]
class KekDecryptorTests
{
    [Test]
    public void CanEncryptString()
    {
        var encyrptor = GenDecryptor();
        string result = encyrptor.Encrypt("TestDek");
        Assert.IsNotEmpty(result);
    }

    [Test]
    public void CanDecryptString()
    {
        var encyrptor = GenDecryptor();
        string testString = "MynameisJonas";
        string encrypted = encyrptor.Encrypt(testString);
        Assert.AreEqual(testString, encyrptor.Decrypt(encrypted));
    }

    private KekDecryptor GenDecryptor()
    {
        var encyrptor = new KekDecryptor();
        encyrptor.AssetTag = "assetTag";
        encyrptor.DevicePassword = "password";
        encyrptor.DeviceSerial = "serial";
        return encyrptor;
    }
}
```

The code for the class is:

```
public class KekDecryptor
{
    public string AssetTag { get; set; }
    public string DeviceSerial { get; set; }
    public string DevicePassword { get; set; }        

    public string Encrypt(string content)
    {
        byte[] kekBytes;
        using (var aesAlg = GenAes())
        {               
            var encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor();

            using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    {
                        swEncrypt.Write(content);
                    }
                    kekBytes = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
        return Convert.ToBase64String(kekBytes);
    }

    public string Decrypt(string content)
    {
        string plaintext;

        byte[] iv, key;
        using (var aes = GenAes())
        {
            Byte[] cipherText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);                

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
            using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor())
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
                plaintext = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

        }

        return plaintext;
    }

    private Aes GenAes()
    {
        var result = Aes.Create();
        byte[] iv, key;
        using (var sha256Alg = SHA256.Create())
        {
            // Create IV (asset tag, hashed)
            iv = sha256Alg.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AssetTag));
            Array.Resize(ref iv, result.BlockSize / 8);

            // Create key (serial + PIN, hashed)
            key =
                sha256Alg.ComputeHash(
                    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Concat(DeviceSerial,
                        DevicePassword)));
        }
        result.IV = iv;
        result.Key = key;

        return result;
    }
}
```

I've tried various things, like setting the position in the streams (stream not seekable exception), reorganizing the stream using statements, and a few other things, nothing has worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been at this for a couple days and my next step is to perform an exorcism.

______________________EDIT________________________

```
     at System.Buffer.BlockCopy (System.Array src, System.Int32 srcOffset,    System.Array dst, System.Int32 dstOffset, System.Int32 count) [0x000a7] in   /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/ReferenceSources/Buffer.cs:61   at    mono.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricTransform.FinalDecrypt (System.Byte[] inputBuffer, System.Int32 inputOffset, System.Int32 inputCount) [0x00074] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Cryptography/SymmetricTransform.cs:431 
 at Mono.Security.Cryptography.SymmetricTransform.TransformFinalBlock (System.Byte[] inputBuffer, System.Int32 inputOffset, System.Int32 inputCount) [0x00034] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Cryptography/SymmetricTransform.cs:488 
 at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count) [0x00318] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/cryptostream.cs:278 
 at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadBuffer () [0x0002b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs:586 
 at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadToEnd () [0x00055] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs:451 
at Client.Services.KekDecryptor.Decrypt (System.String content) [0x0003c] in Client\Services\KekDecryptor.cs:73 
at Client.UnitTests.Tests.KekDecryptorTests.CanDecryptString () [0x00016] in Client.UnitTests\Tests\KekDecryptorTests.cs:29 
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3511/501e63ce/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:305
```

Comment: do you get a stack trace? can you point at the line where exception `System.ArgumentException : Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from the index to the end of the source collection.` occurs?

Comment: I edited my post to include the stack trace. The error occurs at the line
   > plaintext = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

Comment: So I did solve the issue in the android test, feels a bit silly but I was converting the string into byte[] improperly on decryption. I needed to use Convert.FromBase64String() instead of Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes().  

I do still get the visual studio test error which would be nice to solve, but it is not critical.

Comment: @MattJohnson To dismiss your error, specify the Padding in your AES `result.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7`